# Ocultar um item do NavBar no React JS de acordo com a pagina

Tags: react, header, nav-bar

Sou nova utilizando React, fiz cursos no Alura, porém muitas duvidas permanecem por ser algo muito novo pra mim. 
Eu tenho uma pagina de login, essa pagina de login esta utilizando um Header que é usado em todas as outras paginas do projeto. Esse Header possui um NavBar com alguns botões, um desses botões é o "Login" que leva para a pagina de Login. Meu problema é: eu preciso ocultar o botão de Login apenas quando eu estiver na pagina de Login, e como faço isso?

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header'; 
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'; 
import M from 'materialize-css'; 
import '../App/App.css'; 
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle'; 
import Lock from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };   };

  componentDidMount() {
    M.Tabs.init(this.Tabs);   };

  render() {

    const { showResults } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        // (resto do código da pagina)
      </div>

    );   
  } 
};

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../Header/Header.css";
import LinkWrapper from "../../Utils/LinkWrapper";

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <div className="nav-wrapper deep-purple">
                <LinkWrapper to="#"  activeStyle={{}} className="logoSpace"><i className="material-icons sizeLink"><img src="corset.png" className="logoSize"></img></i> Shop</LinkWrapper>
                <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><LinkWrapper to="#" className="waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons sizeLink"><img src="search.png" className="sizeImg"></img></i></LinkWrapper></li>
                    <li><LinkWrapper to="badges.html"><i className="material-icons sizeLink"><img src="cart.png" className="sizeImg"></img></i></LinkWrapper></li>
                    <li><LinkWrapper to="/"><i className="sizeLogin">Login</i></LinkWrapper></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
export default Header;
```

LinkWrapper.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const LinkWrapper = (props) => {
    return (
        <NavLink activeStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} {...props} />
    );
};

export default LinkWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma função própria da window que pode te auxiliar nessa primeira abordagem. Seria a window.location.pathname. ela retorna o endpoint que o navegador se encontra.

```
{window.location.pathname !== "/login" ? <li><LinkWrapper to="/"><i className="sizeLogin">Login</i></LinkWrapper></li> : ''}
```

Segue o como ficaria abaixo, por gentileza.

```
<div className="nav-wrapper deep-purple">
   <LinkWrapper to="#"  activeStyle={{}} className="logoSpace">
     <i className="material-icons sizeLink"><img src="corset.png" className="logoSize"></img></i> Shop
   </LinkWrapper>
   <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><LinkWrapper to="#" className="waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons sizeLink"><img src="search.png" className="sizeImg"></img></i></LinkWrapper></li>
      <li><LinkWrapper to="badges.html"><i className="material-icons sizeLink"><img src="cart.png" className="sizeImg"></img></i></LinkWrapper></li>
      {window.location.pathname !== "/login" ? <li><LinkWrapper to="/"><i className="sizeLogin">Login</i></LinkWrapper></li> : ''}
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const Header = (props) => {
  const { login } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      { !login && <button> login </button> }
    </div>
  )  
}
```

```js
const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header login />
      <form>
      ...
      </form>
    </div>
  )  
}
```